# How to toggle the clicked nav button color in jQuery Mobile when I'm using its UI

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I'm developing a website for mobile. I'm trying to make the website look like ordinary iPhone app, so I want to use jQuery Mobile's nav UI at the bottom. But I meet the problem when I get to add/remove its color binding to click action. I added JavaScript as below

```
function collect () {
if ($("#collect").hasClass("ui-btn-active")) {
    $("#collect").removeClass("ui-btn-active");
    removeCollect();
} else {
    addCollect();
}
}
```

The JavaScript doesn't work. So, I wonder if I should rewrite some function or take another way to realize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just create a custom theme. I think what you have above is fine. Does the element that contains these buttons have a theme? If you are using the default one I would expect to see the default theme. I'm not sure if that answers your question. We may need some more detail on this.

From what I read above it seems you are unhappy with the active state of the button.

Comment: thanks for your answer.I remove the ui-btn-active attribute because I want to make the button like a check-box-style.Maybe my poor English mislead you.

Comment: as my html code is something like <div data-role = "navbar"><ul><li><a href ="" data-role = "check" id = "collect"></li></ul></div>, but when I clicked the button,after my"function collect()"ran,the button will get its ui-btn-active attribute again.So I added a setTimeout to solve the problem.I wish you understood what I mean, my English's really poor,thanks again

Comment: and Im still doubting about my solution,will it still works in the future after the product goes online.If you got what I said,plz give me some more advice,thank you

Comment: You may need to set ui-disabled on the button when the button is set to an in-active state. I know I had to use that before and you could set that so the button becomes in-active. This doesn't necessarily disable the functional aspect of the button you may have to set a variable state for the clicked button (checkbox) and check to see if the state is disabled. - I'm not sure if that helps more.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you should look at JQuery Themeroller. http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/index.php